# VBA Change Pivot Month Filter Dynamic

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to change pivot filter and I want to select the previus month from the current but the code doesn’t do anything For example the filter is “Sep” and I want to go to “Oct” we have November I need to run the macro and change the filter to “Oct”

```
Sub PivotChange()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim WBM As Workbook
Set WBM = Workbooks("MASTER SellOut.xlsx")
Dim SellOut As Worksheet
Set SellOut = WBM.Worksheets("SellOut")
Dim pf As PivotField

Set pf = SellOut.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date")

Dim pi As PivotField
Dim strMonth As String

' current month as string
strMonth = Format(Date, "mmm")

' refresh pivottable

SellOut.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh

With SellOut.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date")
    On Error Resume Next
    ' check, if pivotfield exists
    Set pi = .PivotField(strMonth)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not pi Is Nothing Then
        pi.Visible = True
        For Each pi In .PivotField
            If pi.Name <> strMonth Then pi.Visible = False
        Next pi
    End If
End With

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `pi` should be `PivotItem` not `PivotField` :

```
Dim pi As PivotItem
...
With pf
    On Error Resume Next
    ' check, if pivotfield exists
    Set pi = .PivotItems(strMonth)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not pi Is Nothing Then
        pi.Visible = True
        For Each pi In .PivotItems
            If pi.Name <> strMonth Then pi.Visible = False
        Next pi
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Run time error 13 in line Set pf = SellOut.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date")

Comment: My answer did not modifiy anything about `pf` variable, did you?

Comment: No this code from recorder work fine but is static:  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date").CurrentPage = "Oct"

Comment: what is `SellOut`? it should be `Worksheet` type object pointing to proper worksheet

Comment: sorry it's declaration Dim WBM As Workbook
Set WBM = Workbooks("MASTER SellOut.xlsx")
Dim SellOut As Worksheet
Set SellOut = WBM.Worksheets("SellOut")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202272/discussion-between-vaggelis-and-avb).

Comment: ok i will start again tomorrow i thing i have problem because the date field is in Greek language thank you very much avb!